# On some recent closed questions and community input

Tags: discussion

Some of you may have come across a question that was quickly closed, even though it was answerable. Perhaps a few even noticed something was fishy with question poster.

Well, we can't mention specifics, but there is a StackExchange-wide suspended user who keeps attempting to circumvent their suspension by creating sock-puppets. Sometimes their questions are deleted as soon as they are noticed. Other times, users notice them first and give them a good answer. This poses a dilemma. On the one hand, the questions aren't uniformly poor and may be of interest (and votes) to users. On the other hand, allowing questions to remain visible encourages their continued trolling across the network.

Now, this user does not only post on Latin, but we do have some say in how certain aspects of rule-breaking can be handled. This is where the community can weigh in.

We have proposed two options for this user's questions, but please feel free to vote up or down the options you agree with or disagree with respectively, or propose something of your own. As the problem reaches beyond our site, some suggestions might be impossible, but of course it's still worth airing out those opinions.

The chief two options as we see it are, when encountering this user's evading account, we:

a) suspend the user, close the thread, but allow the community to see the question and ask the question anew (in their own words); or

b) suspend the user and delete the thread, thereby vanishing it from the community altogether. If a user saw it before it was deleted and they are so motivated, they are free to ask the same question (in their own words) from their own account.

Comment: Are most of the questions by this individual valid questions for the community?

Comment: @Adam: Hmm I'd say many are about a valid subject, though often difficult to answer without speculation; the main problem is that they are almost always formulated and formatted in a way that makes them very hard to read.

Comment: I'm a bit confused: the "dilemma" mentioned at the beginning of this post (close vs. don't close) is quite different from the two proposed options (delete vs. don't delete), right? Is deletion ever a normal moderation action for a low-quality question? I don't feel like I have the context to vote which is better.

Comment: @brianpck Deletion is indeed not a normal moderator action for a low quality question. Normally it would just be closed and voted down, which in turn triggers automatic deletion after a while if there is no answer. Doing that with in this unusual case is one of the options. The other one is quick manual deletion for the purpose of giving a known troll zero visibility and zero encouragement. We will suspend the user account no matter what.

Comment: This single user has caused a *lot* of work for moderators and staff across the network over several years. I fear that giving them rope here would encourage them to pester other sites, so whether the individual question is good for us is secondary. If it's good, it should be reasked. It helps also by giving the question the ownership of am active user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This option opts for suspending the user **and** deleting the question.

Comment: I personally have no patience with trolls, on this or any other site. The less "air-time" they have, the better, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

This option opts for suspending the user and closing the question but **not** deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

My view is that moderators should not act differently at all. Why should it matter if the user is "sock-puppets" or not? Bluntly put: If the question is bad - act as if the question is bad. if the user is bad - act accordingly.

StackExcehnage cannot win this war like this - i.e., by specific moderator actions on specific user(s). If it is important for SE,  they should have a tool to recognize those kinds of users automatically - to have a solution by structure.

Hence my suggestion is not to suspend the user at all if their actions on Latin SE do not deserve this kind of severe action. I'm not a fan (to say the least) of deciphering/analyzing specific users psychologically saying this or another action by MODs will result in this or that result.

If the user must be suspended based on violating SE rules, ideally their posts should be deleted as soon as possible - that's why I say it should be solved by structure. If the post already has some positive engagement I would vote to delete it nevertheless simply because it violates the rules of SE. If the post already had some very nice answer(s) - that answer merits a new question by another user/community question.

Comment: Moderators have tools that help us identify whether some user accounts correspond to the same person. Some amount of automation exists, but manual work is also needed. It is an unfortunate but necessary part of keeping the sites clean from problem users. The SE policy is not to disclose details of these tools to avoid anyone gaming the system in matters like this, but one extremely powerful tool that is not a secret is discussion between moderators from different sites. That helps track patterns across the whole network, and those patterns are far more telling than what we see locally.

Comment: I agree that more automation would be a good solution, but we just don't have that and there are reasons to believe we won't be having that any time soon. A part of being a moderator is the janitorial duty of looking at the various sources of information on problematic users and acting accordingly. Sometimes, as in the case of the OP of some of the recent questions this post is about, we local moderators simply enforce network-wide policies. Our site has a very low influx of such problems, fortunately, and we have some freedom in choosing how to go about the details.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, thanks for those comments. I am obviously not so familiar with the SE eco-system and how it works behind the scenes (and that's a good policy of SE not to share this info with users). what makes a question trolling? what makes a question bad for the community?  I mean if that user was using the computer at the local library and used somewhat different language and formatting - if that user were not suspended based on his question - why the other should?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta. Now, I would like to pass the ball back to SE. if the question is enough time online (even 2 minutes) to entice good engagement from users - I say this is the failure of SE.  In principle, the idea in my mind this means that the hands of MODs should be tied in case of failure: this is now the issue of the community, and let them decide if they want this question - and positive votes are one way to show it.  I've read what is written, maybe I should think about this more. but that's my opinion for now.

Comment: @d_e For privacy reasons, we cannot say exactly what this user has done. What I can say is that it's not all bad questions (many of which have consistently attracted a plethora of downvotes), but there is a lot of rule breaking, and not just minor things. There are other users that have a bunch of downvoted questions. This is different.

Comment: I also want to emphasize something Joonas said: "we have some freedom in choosing how to go about the details." There is no war. We're just unsure of what to do with this very narrow, limited case: for banned users who try to evade bans, should their questions be closed but left visible or deleted. I think your last paragraph is in favor of that second option.

Comment: @cmw, okay. I see. in that case I'm indeed for deleting the question as I said in the last paragraph. The reasoning for this should be no other than violating SE rules.